# In ubuntu, is there anything analogous to OS X's dragging a file into terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm new to ubuntu, coming from OS X, where I could drag a folder or file from finder into terminal and have the path to it appear at the prompt (useful e.g. with cd). Is there a way to do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has [already been implemented](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/19920/). What version of Ubuntu are you using? Upgrading should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar and possibly useful is the **nautilus-open-terminal** plugin which lets you right-click on a folder in Nautilus and open a terminal at that location.